# All checkbox clicked from @input value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a @Input in my conponent and based on that I would like to build an input and checkbox.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-aside',
  templateUrl: './aside.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./aside.component.css']
})
export class AsideComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() Segmenty;
 @Output() checkedSegment : EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter();


  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


}
```

My current html :

```
<div *ngFor ="let segment of Segmenty" >
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" > {{segment}}
 <button (click)="allclickedSegment()"></button>
</div>
```

How to build html and a function that will collect to @Output all the checkboxes I clicked into the array.

The array that can be returned is the letters between :

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'
```

Comment: Each time user click the checkbox you want to return what? Please explain your desired output behavior and also what is the problem you are facing with html?

Comment: I think maybe I may add a button and each time user click a button return all cliecked values (between A,B,C,B,E,F,G)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, on each click to segment you pass the index of that segment to allclickedSegment() function and then u store the indexes in an array(),
then u can return the specific letters based on the indexes array, (or u can store a static key/value object that represents those letters based on the segments indexes.
(this approach only works when the letters returned are the same length as the segments in the template).

Comment: My button place is wrong. After button click I want return all clicked input with array of letters lists. The buton must be after div.

Comment: well, then i suggest working with reactive forms, with FormArray on each checkbox u could listen to those changes and on each change you save the checkboxes state